# Why do we check both the value and type when check if a database query was successful?

Tags: php, mysql, database

While I was on w3schools learning about MySQL and PHP, I came across this when on the page about inserting data.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

When checking the query was successful, why do we check if both are the same type and equal? Wouldn't it be fine if it was just this?

```
if ($conn->query($sql) == TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: Your second example is identical to the first. It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Perhaps the sample author has been trying to overcompensate for the lack of parameter binding.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli::query()` returns false on failure, another result will be always not false. You can write without equaling with true if you don't need to use special logic for mysqli_result. [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

```
if ($conn->query($sql)) 
{
  //
} else 
{
  //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Php supports truthyness do if the function returned 1 then it would be true. It's explicitly checking that the result is the Boolean TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

You do NOT need to check type in THIS case and could just have:

```
if ($conn->query($sql) == TRUE) {
```

The author is probably using a defensive programming technique which is to validate exactly what you are expecting.

According to: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
If this is a "SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN" then you would get an object back.  If somebody updated the query to something unexpected, they would hit the error condition and know they had done something wrong.  This particular scenario is a little off because it's sample code.  In reality you would probably have a test to do the real validation.